# UITableView to another UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have in my project UIViewcontroller with UITableview, and in every cell there is a line with some text, and i want that when the user click on on of the cells the app will go to another UItableView with one cell and there the user can edit the cell text.

it's some thing like the properties in the iphone.

Comment: use http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: are you asking for code? there are tutorials online which you can follow to learn the working of tableViews. Go thro' them.

Comment: i looking for some thing built in the ios because i dont want to build couple of uiview controllers for this

Comment: i don't think that there are some native tableview methods that allow you to edit the text of cell, you have to make a separate EditView controller for cell's text editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just call another view containing the tableView.

So, in `didSelectRowForIndexPath`, you type something like:

```
TableViewNumberTwo *otherView = [[TableViewNumberTwo alloc] init];
otherView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:otherView animated:YES];
[otherView release]
```

The second view (TableViewNumberTwo) has the same functions as the first view, which contains your `didSelectRowForIndexPath`. That means you've got two classes (four, if you count the .h-classes), each containing the `numberOfSections`, `numberOfRows`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

This might work out better then just reloading your table with new data. It also gives you an opportunity to expand the app with a navigation controller or something like that. If you really want it all cropped in one class (which I don't recommend because it'll be a big class), you have to reload the table (`[tableView reloadData];`) with a new dataset.

Good luck :)